# Unable to get trace file for WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm unable to get trace log file for WCF service on server. The file simply doesn't appear after I call the service.
I have no problem to get it on client with same configuration.

I'm using windows Windows Web Server 2008 R2, .net 4.0 and the service is hosted in IIS

My Config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="C:\messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
            <add initializeData="C:\tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Beh">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="655360000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="500000000" maxStringContentLength="500000000"
            maxArrayLength="500000000" maxBytesPerRead="500000000" maxNameTableCharCount="500000000" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfService1.PleasureKraftService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Beh" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WebBinding" name="Basic" contract="WcfService1.IMyService"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="WcfService1.IMyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="52428800" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Ent" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Eu;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if IIS has read/write access on the logging folder. From config it looks like you are logging on C$. IIS User should have read-write access on the log folder (give MachineName\User account Modify access on the folder). Also please move your logging to some folder instead of C$.

Hope this helps.